# setting textarea val after load web in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have loaded a web page using jquery into an iframe

```
$("#frame").attr("src", "website"); //this website is **external** web!
```

and I want to set value of textarea inside this iframe for example when clicking

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "#button", function() {
    document.getElementById('textareaID').value = 'new value';
    $('textarea#textareaID').val('new value');
});
```

it does not work in both ways any ideas?

Comment: Your code will be out of textarea or inside ?

Comment: Please provide more detail to make the question clearer.  It would be helpful if you could show the basics of where each of the elements in your jQuery exist within the HTML.  Please provide the HTML that is relevant.

Comment: You cannot do this. Code outside of the iframe cannot modify the objects within the iframe, it would be very dangerous in regards to security. For instance, websites could give themselves permissions to your Facebook.

Comment: Is this website inside your iframe other than the website outside? If that's true, this is your problem, cause you cannot set a value in another domain, it's a secure issue. But if both pages are in the same domain, please, show us all the code you have, and then we can help you.

Comment: howderek yeah I just realized this I try different method curl to any variable then post into iframe + cookies and IT WORKS! :D

Answer (score 0):

Give a name to that frame and access the elements within that frame as  window.frames["framename"].document.getElementById("textareaID").value="new value";

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery contents() and find() functions to be able to detect elements inside the iframe and then change the dom:

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "#button", function() {
    $("#idOfYourIframe").contents().find("#textareaID").val("NEW VALUE");
});
```

Comment: its working but in different way
cURL + Cookies + iframe